# Android Studio: Create a method that try the connection to internet

Tags: android, android-studio, methods, retrofit2, internet-connection

I want to know how to create a method that when detect there is not any connection to internet in the mobile and then the method try to connect with a server every 5 seconds, please if you can put a example to how implement with retrofit it i will appreciated!, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)

Answer (score 0):

May be this code help you.

```
 ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            } else {
                if (isShowAlert) {

                     Toast.makeText(context,
                    "NOT Internet Connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: This only check if a device connected to a connection, but don't check if the  internet is on or off.

Comment: you need to call continuous this method when you  call web service or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) yourContext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

Check

```
if(isNetworkAvailable()){
     // connected to internet
}else{
    // not connected
}
```

Comment: This only check if a device connected to a connection, but don't check if the  internet is on or off.

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpfull,

```
int intervalTime = 5000; // 5 sec
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()  {   
 @Override
 public void run() {
  internetConnection();
   }
 }, intervalTime);


public class InternetConnection {

    /** CHECK WHETHER INTERNET CONNECTION IS AVAILABLE OR NOT */
    public static boolean checkConnection(Context context) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (activeNetworkInfo != null) { // connected to the internet
            Toast.makeText(context, activeNetworkInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (activeNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                // connected to wifi
                return true;
            } else if (activeNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This only check if a device connected to a connection, but don't check if the  internet is on or off.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to check every time.
Define a Connectivity Change broadcast listener in your manifest and project and check connection just when the connectivity changes ( The code provided to you by @Priyank Virani )

There are some special cases which you should handle. some times the wifi is on and you are connected to a local wifi. You need to enter a password to use internet.(like libraries,airports , etc ...) in this situations the above code return true as internet is connected but in reality its false !!!! You should check it either with calling a webService you provided or by calling an api from a famous service in net.

Calling network related things every 5 seconds, prevent device from sleeping and have a very bad effect on battery of device

Answer (score 0):

Previously I use one of these methods from [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out):

```
public static int isInternetActiveWithPing() {
  try {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
    int exitValue = process.waitFor();
    return exitValue;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    return -1;
  }
}

public static boolean isInternetActiveWithInetAddress() {
  try {
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
    return inetAddress != null && !inetAddress.toString().equals("");
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

But it has a major drawback, which we need to always check if the internet is off or not.

The best way is using [NetworkEvents](https://github.com/pwittchen/NetworkEvents/). This library listening network connection state and change of the WiFi signal strength with **Event Bus** which also check if there is the internet connected or not.

By using [NetworkEvents](https://github.com/pwittchen/NetworkEvents/), you don't need to recheck internet connection every 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! well i was trying with networkEvent to disconnect the internet from my wifi but does not detected that there is not internet, just when i turn off the wifi is that the "OnEvent" method is called, you know how to solved it?

Comment: Have you enable internet checking with something like: `networkEvents = new NetworkEvents(context, busWrapper)
  .enableInternetCheck();`?

Comment: yes , i did this    networkEvents = new NetworkEvents(getApplicationContext(), busWrapper).enableInternetCheck().setPingParameters("www.google.com",80,3000);   but with this tell me when i connect to a wifi if there internet or not but is the internet state change , the functino doesnt tell me

Comment: Have you define the Event Listener and catch the respected change with `@Subscribe public void onEvent(ConnectivityChanged event) {
  // get connectivity status from event.getConnectivityStatus()
  if(event.getConnectivityStatus() == ConnectivityStatus.WIFI_CONNECTED_HAS_INTERNET) { // is connected to internet} else if (event.getConnectivityStatus() == WIFI_CONNECTED_HAS_NO_INTERNET) { // no internet connection}
}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a handle that runs in erver 5 sec

```
 Handler myHandler = new Handler();
            myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(isNetWorkAvailable(getActivity()))
                      {
                       webService();
                      }

                    else
                    {
                       //NO NETWORK
                     }
                }
            };
            myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 5000);// runs in ever 5 sec



     private void webservice() {
        // create 2 getters and setters java classes ie..LoginRequest & LoginResponse
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(userEmail, userPassword);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.show();
        Call<LoginResponse> call = GApiClient.get().postWithFormParams(loginRequest);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.i("Response ", "Present");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                   RetrofitError retrofitError;
                  if (e instanceof RetrofitError) {
                     retrofitError = ((RetrofitError) e);
                  if (retrofitError.getKind() == RetrofitError.Kind.NETWORK) {
                      return "Network is down!";
                      }
    }
                Log.i("Response ", " error");
            }
        });


    }




     public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (null != activeNetwork) {
                return TYPE_WIFI;
            }
            return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
        }


        public static boolean isNetWorkAvailable(Context context) {
            int status = getConnectivityStatus(context);
            if (status != 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Apiclient class for retrofit 2.2

```
public class GApiClient {
    private static GServiceApi REST_CLIENT;


    public static final String API_URL = "YOUR BASE URL";
    static {
        setupRestClient();
    }


    private ApiClient() {

    }

    public static ServiceApi get() {
        return REST_CLIENT;
    }

    private static void setupRestClient() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL_TEST)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        REST_CLIENT = retrofit.create(GServiceApi.class);
    }

}
```

Create a interface ServiceApi

```
public interface ServiceApi {


    @POST("/verify/json") //rest of url
    Call<Employee> postWithFormParams(@Body UserDetails data);

}
```

Comment: Goodin retrofit part. Code only checks if a device connected to a connection, but don't check if the  internet is on or off.

Comment: not getting ur scenario... above code checks if there is  a internet connection

Comment: You can try by connecting your device to a WiFi Access point which not connected to the internet. Or trying using a local network.

Comment: ok i understand.You can check that only by  communcation timeout  occurs and the call to retrofit onFailure occurs